How to Extract Preprocessed Variables in Recipes from Tidymodels
I’m using the recipes package from the tidymodels to preprocess my data. I’ve applied a series of preprocessing steps using recipe() to two different groups. I’m trying to compare which variables were preprocessed differently between two groups.
My Questions:
How can I extract the list of variables that were transformed in each step?
Thank you!
I stored the prep() results and tried to find the variables processed in each step, but it was not clear to me how the output is organized.

I believe the best way for you to get that info is to tidy() the prepped recipe:
library(recipes)

rec <- 
  recipe(mpg ~ ., mtcars) |> 
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())

## before preprocessing is applied:
tidy(rec, number = 1)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#>   terms                    statistic value id             
#>   <chr>                    <chr>     <dbl> <chr>          
#> 1 all_numeric_predictors() <NA>         NA normalize_M0mBp

Before you apply prep() the recipe does not store which columns were chosen (because they haven't been chosen yet) but after prep() the info is there:

## after preprocessing is applied:
prep(rec) |> tidy(number = 1)
#> # A tibble: 20 × 4
#>    terms statistic   value id             
#>    <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>          
#>  1 cyl   mean        6.19  normalize_M0mBp
#>  2 disp  mean      231.    normalize_M0mBp
#>  3 hp    mean      147.    normalize_M0mBp
#>  4 drat  mean        3.60  normalize_M0mBp
#>  5 wt    mean        3.22  normalize_M0mBp
#>  6 qsec  mean       17.8   normalize_M0mBp
#>  7 vs    mean        0.438 normalize_M0mBp
#>  8 am    mean        0.406 normalize_M0mBp
#>  9 gear  mean        3.69  normalize_M0mBp
#> 10 carb  mean        2.81  normalize_M0mBp
#> 11 cyl   sd          1.79  normalize_M0mBp
#> 12 disp  sd        124.    normalize_M0mBp
#> 13 hp    sd         68.6   normalize_M0mBp
#> 14 drat  sd          0.535 normalize_M0mBp
#> 15 wt    sd          0.978 normalize_M0mBp
#> 16 qsec  sd          1.79  normalize_M0mBp
#> 17 vs    sd          0.504 normalize_M0mBp
#> 18 am    sd          0.499 normalize_M0mBp
#> 19 gear  sd          0.738 normalize_M0mBp
#> 20 carb  sd          1.62  normalize_M0mBp

Created on 2024-05-26 with reprex v2.1.0
